# Show all available routes in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I'm new with Kibana and Elasticsearch also and want to use some API to investigate the connection between them. But got some errors when testing.

Ex: when I run `/api/saved_objects/_find?type=index-pattern` It worked,
but some APIs does not. It responses "not found" and not like the doc, such as GET `api/saved_objects/index-pattern/my-pattern`. return 

`{
"statusCode": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "Not Found"
}`

So my question is how can I show all available routes of Kiabana's app like Rails with `rake routes`

P/s: For now I want to custom the core-plugin of Kibana's app, but it's difficult to find a document or articles about this. Information in the official doc is not enough for me. If you know any resources, can you please share them with me. Thank you.

Comment: I would start here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api.html

Comment: This is where I start and got the error. So I wonder if It has a problem with my route setting. And this is the reason I want to list up all routes.

Comment: What version of Kibana are you running?

Comment: I am using  6.3.1

Comment: Well, are you sure that an index pattern with id `my-pattern` actually exists?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to remove then prefix "index-pattern:" of _id before paste. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing something in the URL. If the ID of your index pattern in the Kibana index is `index-pattern:my-pattern` then you can GET it like this:

```
api/saved_objects/index-pattern/my-pattern
                               ^
                               |
              you need to remove the prefix here
```

Comment: Including prefix cause `not found` response. My mistake is copied all the value of `_id` property in Dev-Tool tab result, that includes prefix `index-patten:`. I removed and it works. But thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: this is response from Dev-Tool tab `"_id": "index-pattern:d64fce50-042b-11e9-aaa7-0fbfcb8ec9e2",`

Comment: makes sense, I've adapted my answer accordingly.